# Grails - How to render partial unescaped JSON inside a Meta tag in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, json, grails, web, meta

I'm passing a JSON String (`{"myData":"data"}`) to my rendered page like so:

```
render(view: 'myPage', model: [jsonData: JSONStr]);
```

then on the page template:

```
<meta content='http://www.myDomain.com/video?config=${ (jsonData) }' property="og:video" />
```

the result is:

```
<meta content='http://www.myDomain.com/video?config={&quot;myData&quot;:&quot;data&quot;}' property="og:video" />
```

Is There a way to prevent escaping of the JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a TagLib

```
class SimpleTagLib {

 def unescaped = { attrs ->
      out << attrs.value  
  }

}
```

---

```
<meta content='http://www.myDomain.com/video?config=${g.noEncode(value:jsonData)}' property="og:video" />
```